# Асинхронность цикла

Tags: c#

Не совсем могу понять работу асинхронности. Есть телеграм бот на библиотеке Telegram Bot C# и я сделал бота по [этому примеру](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples/blob/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Polling/Handlers.cs)
Цель: общаться с Tcp сервером асинхронно, не блокируя поток, чтобы в это время бот мог общаться с другими пользователями

Я попробовал проверить работу асинхронности.
Почему, если я использую

```
async Task testFunct() {
  while (true) {
  }
}
```

И вызываю так (Сама функция вызывается из асинхронной функции BotOnMessageReceived - если человек написал текст боту или BotOnCallbackQueryReceived - если человек нажал на кнопку.)

```
testFunct() 
или Task task = Task.Run(() => testFunct());
```

То поток блокируется. А если использую

```
async Task testFunct() {
  client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
  while (true) {
    if (client.Available > 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

(при этом Available всегда 0 т.к я не посылаю ничего), то поток не блокируется при вызове из BotOnMessageReceived, а если вызывать из BotOnCallbackQueryReceived, то опять нарываюсь на блокировку..

Comment: `await` уберите, будет вам тогда "фоном".

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).